# Is this a valid implementation of Memento Pattern in C#?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, .net, memento

I've been studying design patterns from GOF for a few weeks, especially in C#, and I'm struggling with Memento Pattern. I know there are a lot of C# implementations on the web, but I came up with my own version of it. The question is: although it diverges from GOF UML, is it still reasonable and valid considering SOLID principles?

What is your opinion?

```cs
interface IMemento
{
    List<IMemento> Mementos { get; set; }

    void SetMemento();
    IMemento? GetMemento(uint index);
    IMemento? GetPreviousMemento() => (Mementos.Count > 1) ? Mementos[Mementos.Count - 2] : null; // Optional method
}

class Subject : IMemento // Originator
{

    public Subject(string prop1, int prop2)
    {
        Prop1 = prop1;
        Prop2 = prop2;
        SetMemento();
    }

    private string _prop1;
    public string Prop1 
    {
        get => _prop1;
        set
        {
            _prop1 = value;
            SetMemento();
        }
    }

    private int _prop2;
    public int Prop2
    {
        get => _prop2;
        set
        {
            _prop2 = value;
            SetMemento();
        }
    }

    public List<IMemento> Mementos { get; set; } = new List<IMemento>(); // Caretaker

    public void Method1() { }
    public void Method2() { }

    public void SetMemento() => Mementos.Add((IMemento)MemberwiseClone());
    public IMemento? GetMemento(uint index) => (index < Mementos.Count) ? Mementos[(int)index] : null;
    public IMemento? GetPreviousMemento() => (Mementos.Count > 1) ? Mementos[Mementos.Count - 2] : null;
}
```

I've already tested and from my point of view, the only big problem can be with memory consumption, but that is a normal issue when it comes to Memento and it can be solved with Flyweight, for example.

=========================== UPDATE ==============================

After some rethinking, I came up with this implementation, but I still think it's kinda of naive. However, it maybe be interesting if improved.

````cs
interface IOriginator<T>
{
    T SaveMemento();
    void RestoreMemento(T memento);
}

interface ISubjectMemento
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; } // States
}

class Subject : IOriginator<SubjectMemento>, ISubjectMemento // Originator
{
    public Subject(string prop1, int prop2, bool prop3)
    {
        Prop1 = prop1;
        Prop2 = prop2;
        Prop3 = prop3;
    }

    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop3 { get; set; }

    public void Method1() { }
    public void Method2() { }

    public SubjectMemento SaveMemento() => new SubjectMemento(Prop1);
    public void RestoreMemento(SubjectMemento memento) => Prop1 = memento.Prop1;
}

class SubjectMemento : ISubjectMemento
{
    public SubjectMemento(string prop1)
    {
        Prop1 = prop1;
    }

    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

class SubjectHistory // Caretaker
{
    private List<SubjectMemento> _mementos { get; set; } = new List<SubjectMemento> { };

    public void Add(SubjectMemento memento) => _mementos.Add(memento);
    public SubjectMemento? Get(uint index) => (index < _mementos.Count) ? _mementos[(int)index] : null;
    public SubjectMemento? GetLast() => (_mementos.Count != 0) ? _mementos[_mementos.Count - 1] : null;
}
```
````

Comment: Do I understand your code correctly that you are calling the SetMemento 3x times during the ctor?

Comment: Are you aware of this fact: *The MemberwiseClone method creates a **shallow** copy by creating a new object, and then copying the nonstatic fields of the current object to the new object.*? [Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-6.0#remarks)

Comment: Also why do you have this `GetPreviousMemento`? What is the use case when it is useful?

Comment: Oh, you're right. I didn't realize these problems at first and after searching more about this pattern, this is not its objective. Thank you, Peter.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ViníciusPereira I've reviewed your new code and I have two questions: Would it make more sense to change the`IOrganitor`'s type parameter from concrete type to interface, like this `IOriginator<ISubjectMemento>`? Would it make sense to use `ISubjectMemento` inside the `SubjectHistory` as well?